# Get intersecting lines in sql spatial

Tags: sql-server, spatial

I'm using Entity Framework 5.0 and sql server geometry type.
I'm trying to take a point and find the lines that intersect a buffer of that point and meet certain attribute requirements. Is this possible?

I know of the STIntersect method but those appear to work as a comparison between two features. I have a line dataset and a single point. so i don't know how many results i could get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the STBuffer geometry method to get an area around a point and store that in a variable (or wherever!). From there, you can use STIntersects to find out if your lines. Like so:

```
DECLARE @g geometry, @l geometry;
SELECT @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(0 0)', 0),
@l = geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 1, 4 0)', 0);

SELECT @g, @l, @g.STBuffer(1), @l.STIntersects(@g.STBuffer(1));
```

Also, my standard caveat of using the right data type (geography vs geometry) applies if you're doing geospatial.

Comment: Great! thanks! but my question was how would i find all of the lineS that intersect my buffered point. I know how to make a one to one comparison but i have many, many lines and i don't want to compare every one of them.

Comment: How are all of your lines stored? If in a table and you have one line per row, just run the above query over the table instead of a variable and you're good to go. If they're stored some other way, you're going to have to be more forthcoming as to the actual structure of your data...

Comment: they are stored in a table. would i have to create a loop or could i do it as a set? and thanks for your help too!

Comment: If it's one line per row, it's pretty simple. `select * from dbo.yourtable where yourcolumn.STIntersects(@g.STBuffer(1))` will work. If the point is *also* in a table somewhere, you'll have to join it somehow. If that's the case, my suggestion would be to write the join without considering the geo data and then add that bit at the end.